# Zebra Gk420d not printing images correctly on Windows 10

Tags: zebra-printers, barcode-printing, windows-10-desktop

I have been printing labels which contain some text and a barcode image (code 128). 
When connected to a PC running Windows 7 Pro 64-bit, the printing was perfect. I have now moved onto a PC running Windows 10 Pro 64-bit, however when printing the label, the text is fine, however the barcode image is fuzzy and cannot be scanned by a barcode scanner. 
I have installed the latest drivers but nothing seems to make a difference. The only configured settings on the printer was the label height and width.

Comment: Try to change printing head temperature settings just before hitting print. This is not a programming question though, so might get closed.

Comment: Thanks Hurtuk, but  the printer is printing its test barcodes fine, but from my .NET application it is not. So I don't think it's a hardware configuration issue. I suspect it's compatibility with Windows 10 perhaps, or something to do with how I am generating the image on my application?

Comment: I suggest you to save the pdf generated to a file in your app, open that file manually and try to print it by hand. It can provide you a lot of insights for what is going on.

Comment: I generated the PDF, it looked clear in the PDF, but printed the same. I think my question is not phrased well and has a lot of missing info. I will edit or repost my question with more relevant information. Sorry about that...

Comment: Still sounds like worth trying old driver versions. But as you pointed out, test barcodes are printing fine so comparison would reveal the reason.